# How to calculate fees for Plutus Smart Contract?

Tags: plutus, plutustx, fee

How can someone calculate fee for executing Plutus smart contract given that they know CPU and Memory Units required for executing Plutus Script?

Answer (score 2):

You can now use fee estimator at https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/plutus-fee-estimator/

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.  OP or somebody who finds this might be looking for an explanation of the formula rather than a tool to do the calculation.

Comment: The formula is a simple multiplication. MemoryUnits X MemoryUnitCost + CPUsteps X CPUstepCost. As for the costs, I honestly don't know the numbers.